# Rational Exponents on Calculator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, computer-algebra-systems, calculator

I'm confused as to why my calculator is saying that $$x^\frac{n}{n}=x$$ when $n$ is an even integer. I was under the impression that $$x^\frac{n}{n}=\sqrt[n]x^n=|x|$$ when $n$ is an even integer. Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: There are three ways to interpret: $(\sqrt[n]x)^n, \sqrt[n]{x^n}$ and $x^{(n/n)}$,each giving a different result.

Answer (score 5):

The basic problem is that the "laws of exponents" such as $(x^a)^{1/b} = x^{a/b} = (x^{1/b})^a$ work for positive $x$ but not always for negative $x$.  Things get even more interesting when complex numbers are involved.

I would have to insist that when you write $x^{n/n}$ it has the meaning $x^{(n/n)}$, and since $n/n = 1$ (at least for $n \ne 0$) this is equal to $x^1 = x$.  Most computer algebra packages take the same view, indeed in a text-based interface you generally can't enter this without the parentheses:

```
x^(n/n)
```

If you want $(x^{n})^{1/n}$ or $(x^{1/n})^n$, you put in parentheses accordingly.

Comment: What would be the error in a "proof" such as the following: $$(-4)=(-4)^1=(-4)^\frac{2}{2}=[(-4)^2]^\frac{1}{2}=[16]^\frac{1}{2}=4$$ therefore $(-4)=4$?

Comment: @Jeffrey, the error would be in $(-4)^{\frac22}=\left((-4)^2\right)^{\frac12}$ where you applied a "law of exponents that is not valid when the base is negative and the exponent factors ($2$ and $1/2$) are not both integers.

Answer (score 1):

The calculator is correct. $\frac {n}{n} = 1$ for all $n \neq 0$. Any argument to the contrary must address that.

Answer (score 0):

$x^{(\frac nn)} =x^1 = x$

$(x^{n})^{\frac 1n}  = |x|$

Note the difference... brackets affect a lot

Comment: To add on that: $(x^{\frac{1}{n}})^n = x$ for all $x$ where $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is defined, namely for all nonnegative reals.

Comment: $x^\frac{n}{n}$ does not contain parenthesis. Therefore, there is no explicit indication that the division needs to be evaluated before it is treated as an exponent.

Comment: @TreeHouse196 You are right. You can treat it as anything. Thecalculator happens to do $\frac nn$ first. I am sure some other calculators do the opposite.